# Why a C code when implementing as DLL is slower in C#

Tags: c#, c, sqlite

I did a C program that reads some values from binary files and write them in a SQLite DB. I transformed the same file in a DLL library and I invoked it from a Windows Form App in C#. Following is an example that illustrates what I want to do:

In C# I use the following

```
[DllImport("Progress.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateDB", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int avance(IntPtr Path);
```

The DLL C code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h >
#include <math.h>
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
EXPORT void CreateDB(int f)
{
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    sleep(1);
    f=i+1;
}
}
```

The variable **f** returns the value that I want to use in the progress bar.

The Exe C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Now that I invoke the C program as DLL, it lasts three times to perform the job. I would expect that the time is very similar than the C exe file. In addition, the progress bar is not updated in real time.

The C# code in the Windows App Form is the following:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 4;
        IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
        progressBar1.Value = avance(strPtr);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

How can I do to solve the speed issue and how can I do to update the progress bar as a loop into the C DLL is running?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is **i** supposed to be an out-parameter? I don't see its value being set anywhere. Also, should **CreateDB** return an int?

Comment: My initial guess is that you're including the time required to load the DLL.  This would not apply if it were part of the EXE that was already running.

Comment: I modified the question adding more information. I hope with this is clearer what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: the progress bar will not change until you return from the function call. You need to do much more fiddly things that make a progress bar that moves while you are calling some other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# code calls the C function as if it took a pointer to an int. But according to your declaration, it takes a plain int. It should work if you change it as follows:

```
EXPORT void CreateDB(int *f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        *f = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all of you for your time. I am still working in trying to update the progress bar.